# Best way to save user entries from a puzzle to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an online exam portal build in codeigniter framework with mysql database. Exam is like sudoku game each student will get 6 sudoku game in exam. At a time there will be 50 - 100 students attending the exam and each one will get different puzzles.

I developed in such a way that when student start the exam it will fetch this 6 row from database and display the UI for puzzles, each time when they enter a number in any box it will save into database.So if 100 students attending the exam that many calls will get fired into database.

So what i am facing now is when number of students is like 20 - 30 exams was smooth and if user increases i am getting connection error like "Too many connection to user" or "failed to connect to mysql database".

So what i am asking you is there any better way to store this user entries and save them at once into database like using any session( if its not increase memory usage ) or client side storage.

Please don't feel bad to read this long text, i am not asking any codes just give me some ideas or latest technologies i can learn and use to improve my application.

Comment: If you get connection issues when your userbase gets above 30-40, then you're doing something wrong, or your host is incredibly bad.

Comment: dont use persistent connections

Comment: @Qirel i am using VPN hosting so i think i need to epitomize my codes

Comment: @DevsiOdedra what you mean by persistent connection, how could we avoid that..

Answer (score 1):

I think increasing/upgrading bandwidth will help you in that case...also you can check monthly visits provided by your hosting provider in your current plan.